# Opencart: get decrypted password from customer table

Tags: opencart

When customer register new account we have to send them a confirmation email, what my question is i need to send each customer confirmation email with attached their login email address and password that they created a while ago... so how can i get their password from my `customer` table from field `password`..?? i just want to echo this `password` customer verification email page where i want....

```
<?php echo $password; ?>
```

any idea.? thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - you can't. Read up on SHA1, MD5, salt and hashing in general. Google is your friend here.

[See Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128746/custom-sha1salt-pass-decode)

Your only option is to remove encryption all together and store it unencrypted, which is not very secure.

On a second thought, if you're doing this confirmation email during registration, then store unencrypted password string in some variable before submiting the form, then use it in your mailing script. Password in the DB will still be encrypted

Answer (score 10):

To be honest, **I hate every website I register to that sends me a confirmation email containing my password!!!** And quickly I regret I did even register...

So the best answer and option for You: **do not send a password back to user** - he knows what password he entered during the registration and even if he lost it he still is able to change it to another one whether using his account management or "Lost password" link.

Comment: Long time ago, websites had to login and safely authenticate users independently. Nowadays its not necessary in many cases. Studies shows that most people leave signup form, or conciently insert wrong data, the use of Social Login makes very much more people sign up and return to the website. But in a e-store its necessary to keep that very simple, offer social options and ask users to create password only after checkout.. When they return to the website. Password should be asked only for change user info, withdraws. Users should use password only if Facebook blocks his account, for example .

Comment: About sending passwords back to users using e-mail, i would say only that  this is a disrespect with the user safety .

Answer (score 1):

If you want so save a copy of the passwords cleartext you need to:

1) Create a new table at your db (for this example table is called temp, containing varchar fields mail and pass)

2) locate registration file: /catalog/model/account/customer.php

3) locate line starting with  :

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "customer SET store_id = '" .
```

should be at about line 14
add a new line after it as following:

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "temp SET mail = '" . $this->db->escape($data['email']) . "', pass = '" . $this->db->escape($data['password']) . "'");
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Open Cart hashes the password with SHA1 in a one-direction encryption. In simple words, that means that the password is not intented to be de-hashed. When the user logs in, the system hashes the user input again and compares the hashes. This is known as one-directional encryption and is considerably safe.

The only common way to decrypt it (let's say a hacker for example) will be by using a collision table that stores all the original and hashed results. To make life harder for hackers, OpenCart also uses a Salt (that creates new differnt collision table for each Salt key) so it is very unlikely to decrypt the password (although SHA-1 is already not recommended by many developers due to currently known volunarabilities and it is probably better to use SHA-256).

That being said, I'd recommend 2 options:

1. Change the encryption to a 2 directional encryption such as php's built in
   `mcrypt_encrypt()/mcrypt_decrypt()`. OpenCart actually helps you with it, look under System/Libaray/encryption.php. You will need to change the catalog/model/account/customer.php model. You will also need to change the controller so that it actually includes $this->data['password'] = $customer_info['password']; This will make sure you can access $password in the .tpl file.
2. Since I'm as well against sending passwords over email, I'd suggest sending a link to the index.php?route=account/forgotten in case the forgot the password.